# which is best using delete or truncate when i need to delete all data from table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2017, sql-function

I work on `sql server 2017`

I need to delete all rows from table `student_course`

but I don't know which is best for use

```
delete from student_course
```

OR

```
truncate table student_course
```

**Tables Structure**

table student_course Structure

```
studentid pk
courseid  pk
```

table student table

```
studentid pk
```

table courses

```
courseid pk
```

---

`student_course` table have relation with courses table and student table

so which command will be used to delete all rows from table `student_course`

truncate or delete ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have an foreign key to the table so I will use delete, instead of truncate.**

but if i not have forign key then i will use truncate because it faster than delete